# how to use getTargetFragment and setTargetFragment to send result to previous fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

**FragmentOne**

i'm Replacing FragmentTwo here

```
Fragment secondFragment = new FragmentTwo();
secondFragment.setTargetFragment(FragmentOne.this, AppConstant.FRAGMENT_CODE);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();            
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, secondFragment);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

From Fragment Two How to send this "Address" String to OnActivityResult Method in FragmentOne. Do I need to Use setArgument or getTargetFragment.

**FragmentTwo**

"How do i Identify FragmentOne then i can Send Result to FragmentOne"

**FragmentOne**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       
     String value = data.getStringExtra("Address");   
}
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an intent with the result and in FragmentTwo just call `getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(AppConstant.FRAGMENT_CODE,Context.RESULT_OK, intent);`